# working with DataTabe, List<> and DataGridView inside nested For Next

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, arraylist, datatable

Im trying to get information out of certain List inside For Next loop to be able to place the data in a DataTable so I can show it in a DataGridView. Well I have been searching and trying for hours but I dont gett the result I want. I think I'm almost there but something I'm doing wrong. Is ther eanybody willing to help me?

```
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Set first column names
        //dt.Columns.Add("Sample No");
        for (int i = 0; i <= frmMain.iAnaChan-1; i++)
        //Loop to add analog channel columns
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(frmMain.AnalogChannelList[i].ch_id.ToString());

        }

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        for (int sam = 1; sam <= frmMain.TotSamples ; sam++)
        {
            
            for (int chan = 0; chan <= frmMain.iAnaChan -1; chan++)
            { 
            
            row[chan] = frmMain.channeldata[sam-1].sSampleVal.ToString();

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }

        }
        
        dataGridViewSampleData.DataSource = dt;
        
    }
```

Class

```
 public class aChannelList
{ 
    //Class for retreiving all Analog Channel information
    public string An { get; set; }
    public string ch_id { get; set; }
    public string ph { get; set; }
    public string ccbm { get; set; }
    public string uu { get; set; }
    public string chanMult { get; set; }
    public string chanOffset { get; set; }
    public string skew { get; set; }
    public string minRange { get; set; }
    public string maxRange { get; set; }
    public string primVal { get; set; }
    public string secVal { get; set; }
    public string scalingID { get; set; }     

}
public class SampledData
{
    //This class retreives the relevant information into a list to give the relevant channel data visible into a datagrid for information
    public string sSampleNo { get; set; }
    public string sTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string sSampleVal { get; set; }
}
```

`iAnaChan` is an integer than should set the amount of "channels" i.e. columns I need. And this works correct if I don't run the below code.
Than I need to start rows, the amount of rows have the values of `frmMain.TotSamples` and place them inside a a For Next loop so it will place the rows automatically. Than I try to add in the columns the sample values in the repectivly columns and add a row. After all loops have been passed thru I try to place it in a DataTable. But unfortunatly this doesn't work and I really would like to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @John, I have added the two classes.
First I know I can use the list as a data source for the DataGrid. But it doesn't show the information aas I want. I retrieve this information from two different files. The `aChannelList.ch_id` comes from one file and this should give me the columns with their name. The `SampledData.sTimeStamp` and `SampledData.sSampleVal` comes from a other file and should be written in the rows. Now when I use `SampledData`as datasource it display (if I have 6 channels) first 6 times `sSampleVal` with the same `sTimeStamp`

Comment: so I get this
Timestamp 1, Value 100
Timestamp 1, Value 50 (for each channel)
Timestamp 2, Value 120
Timestamp 2, Value 60

But I want:
Timestamp 1, Value 100, Value 50
Timestamp 2, Value 120, Value 60

I hope this makes sense to you

Answer (score 0):

You can create `public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }` into which you will add the items using a foreach loop

```
foreach (var item in dataCollection)
    Items.Add(item)
```

Then just set DataGrid's `ItemSource` to `Items`. DataGrid is able to autogenerate  itself this way.

Comment: Ok so the way I try to do this is not possible and I should use a different strategy as you explained here? Pff ok I will have to get into `ObservableCollection<object> Items {get; set;}`. Thnks you for the  information.

Comment: @ElectricRay81 I've done it this way today in an app, so this solution should work and it is way easier than messing around with data tables.

Comment: @Thomas thanks I will get into this to see how it works. I have been struggeling with this for two days with no results that I need. But this is the way to learn ;)